# Android Navigation Component popupTo self

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm using Navigation Component to navigate in my app. I'm working with tree structure and I'm navigating users node by node -> `Node == NodeFragment`. But now I'm struggling with back navigation to particular node.

E.g.: Image navigation stack with look like this `A -> B -> C -> D` when user wants to navigate from node `D` directly to node `B` I want to popup fragment `C, D` and go directly to `B`?

E.g.: You can imagine something like navigating trough folder structure where you are navigation the same fragment again and again. And then you want to go back to particular folder which is not parent of the current one.

But I don't know ho to achieve it with Navigation Component. For navigation I'm using self action. Thanks in advance.

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nodeFragment"
    android:name="com.example.NodeFragment">

    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_chatbotBuilderChildrenFragment_self2"
        app:destination="@id/nodeFragment" />
        
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found some kind of workaround solution which is pretty simple. It seems that calling `NavController.navigateUp()` multiple times in sort period of time works just fine. I'm not sure if this is the right solution but it solves my issues.
I was also supprise that even my fragment transition wasn't break after call `NavController.navigateUp()` multiple times.

Code example:

```
repeat(numberOfPopUps) {
     findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go into your navigation graph, click on the action (the arrow line) on `C -> D`, on the right panel (make sure in design mode instead of split or code mode) you will see `pop up tp` option, then choose `Fragment B`, that's it. So whenever you are in `Fragment D` and you click the `Back` key, the app will nagivate back to `Fragment B`.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Maybe didn't explain my issue well. The problem is that I'm using self action which means I'm navigating to the same fragment again and again. You can image something like navigation trough folders, it's the same case.